# jQuery hide an element if another element contains text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that I wish to hide using jQuery, only if I'm in a certain category, so I want to base the hiding of the div based on my breadcrumbs. I think I have the jQuery right, but it isn't hiding the div?

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Tshirts</li>
        <li>Mens</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="hide-me">I want to hide</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).ready(function(){
        if(jQuery('.breadcrumbs ul.nav li:nth-child(2)').text() == "Tshirts"){
            jQuery('.hide-me').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Works for me. [*demonstration*](http://jsfiddle.net/uPn3p/)

Comment: If you `console.log(jQuery('.breadcrumbs ul.nav li:nth-child(2)').text() == "Tshirts)` what's the output, true or false?

Comment: Don' know if you know about this, but you can rewrite `jQuery(` to the much simpler `$(`.

Comment: Which browser are you using? For me it's ok.

Comment: Why don't you give an ID , `<li id="tshirts">Tshirts</li>` and do it directly?

Comment: yea, I don't understand the usecase for this. Why is it that you want to hardcode for the second list, when you could just assign it an ID?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.breadcrumbs ul.nav li:nth-child(2)').text()
```

Is strange, why are you hardcoding this so much? You're specifically asking for that list, and only if it is within a very specific tree.

It would be easier if you just changed your HTML

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li id="secondlist">Tshirts</li>
        <li>Mens</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and then

```
$("#secondlist").text() == "Tshirts";
```

Comment: Using magento, so this html is very simplified.

Comment: I don't understand, you can't add an ID to the list? How are you adding the class to the div and the ul?

Answer (score 0):

Check if

```
$('.breadcrumbs ul.nav li:nth-child(2)').text()
```

is really getting the value, I think that is the principal problem.